# YUI 3 is going to yui.yahooapis.com to get code. I am HTTPS and content blocked

Tags: yui

I worked this holiday to find out my code wont work on HTTPS. My LOCALDEV is HTTP and our production server is HTTPS.

For some reason YUI is going out to get JS, when I have it locally.

[image]

I have it on the server...........

[image]

And finally my code:

```
    YUI().use('autocomplete', 'autocomplete-filters', 'autocomplete-highlighters', function (Y) {

    var notes = [
        "Dr Follow Up Complete Notes",
        "Fax Document Notes",
        "Event Notes",
        "Email Information Notes",
        "Corresponding Document Notes",
        "Return Call Notes",
        "Admit Notes",
        "Discharge Notes",
        "Other Notes",
        "Excellent Resource Notes",
        "Good Resource Notes",
        "Neutral Resource Notes",
        "Poor Resource Notes",
        "Unacceptable Resource Notes",
    ];

    var inputNode = Y.one('#name');

    inputNode.plug(Y.Plugin.AutoComplete, {
        resultFilters    : 'phraseMatch',
        resultHighlighter: 'phraseMatch',
        source           : notes,
        minQueryLength   : 0
    });
    inputNode.ac.get('boundingBox').setStyle('zIndex', 50);
    inputNode.on('focus', function () {
        inputNode.ac.sendRequest('');
    })
```

==================================================================================

## THIS IS AFTER I ADDED :  base: 'include/javascript/yui3/build'

[image]

I don't have that directory in my build.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TLDR**: try setting the [`base`](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/config.html#property_base) config property in your call to YUI.

I haven't used YUI, but generally speaking, requests from a HTTPS site should always hit other HTTPS sites (otherwise you'll see insecure content warnings, or requests get blocked as you've discovered). So that's the problem.

You have 2 options I can think of to fix this:

1. Configure YUI to request from a HTTPS site. [Google's AjaxAPIs](http://googleajaxsearchapi.blogspot.com.au/2008/11/welcome-yui-scriptaculous-gets-fresh.html) did have it hosted and [did support SSL](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2008/11/19/yui-google/), but it appears to have been removed from [Google's list of hosted libraries](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide). A [post in the YUI forums by a YUI developer in 2011](http://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=29097) indicates Google stopped hosting new versions of YUI due to Google's CDN not supporting combo handling. So that's not really an option, and some people are of the opinion that [external scripts loaded over HTTPS are bad](http://wonko.com/post/javascript-ssl-cdn) anyway.
2. Configure YUI to load the content from your local server. This requires that your javascript is not only locally present but will also be served by your server at a particular URL. Aside from making your initial `script` tag point to your locally hosted YUI script, it [looks like](http://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=9049) configuring the client side loading is done by setting the [`base`](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/config.html#property_base) config property in your call to YUI (or [`comboBase`](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/config.html#property_comboBase) if you are using a combo loader - but that would mean you'd have to [set up your own YUI combo loader](http://yuilibrary.com/projects/phploader)).

For example, if your YUI lib is available at `https://mydomain.com/static/js/yui_3.6.0/yui/build/` (and your page is at, say `https://mydomain.com/sample/page`), then you might do the following:

```
<script src="https://mydomain.com/static/js/3.6.0/yui/build/yui-min.js"></script>
```

And then in your javascript files:

```
YUI({ 
    base: 'static/js/yui_3.6.0/yui/build/'
}).use('node', 'event', function(Y) { 
    ...
})
```

(or possibly `base: '/static/js/yui_3.6.0/yui/build/'`; I haven't got a server handy to test on - please report back which worked, if any!)

Comment: It worked but now it is asking for BUILDAUTOCOMPLETE and I don't have that.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - seems like you may have forgotten to include the trailing slash (`base: 'include/javascript/yui3/build/'`, not `base: 'include/javascript/yui3/build'`)

Comment: Upgrading insecure requests <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests"> refernce : https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content?hl=en

Answer (score 25):

I thought I would share my experience in hopes that someone else may be helped. May not work for others or not. 
I was requesting the following url:
`http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?2.6.0/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js&2.6.0/build/animation/animation-min.js`

But needed https, so I simply changed it from http to https and got a security warning that the cert wasn't valid for the domain. I looked at valid domains and noticed a "yui-s" and thought "Hmmmm secured version?"

I then tried this:
`https://yui-s.yahooapis.com/combo?2.6.0/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js&2.6.0/build/animation/animation-min.js`

Which worked wonderfully. So others try just changing to https and if your subdomain is "yui" change it to "yui-s"

Hope this helps someone

Comment: Heads up: I'm finding that a lot of stuff that exists on yui.yahooapis.com is missing from yui-s.yahooapis.com.  Older versions of YUI2, any of the stuff from the "YUI gallery", etc. that works fine on the yui host is missing from yui-s.

Comment: @FrankFarmer thanks - I guess I got lucky with my file, but for anyone else I suppose it's worth a try. If nothing else, you can download the file locally as jshirley suggests

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are serving the initial yui-min.js file from the CDN. Find this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/..."></script>
```

Replace that to point to your local copy of YUI:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/where/you/put/yui/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
```

That should work and serve the necessary JS off your local server.

However, this will not have any combo loading, which will cause the page to load (sometimes a *lot* slower. You can read a good article about combo loading YUI locally at http://blog.endpoint.com/2011/02/locally-served-yui3.html

Comment: JSHIRLEY will you contact me at michaelwjoyner at g-mail-dot.com

Comment: You still need to configure the `base` property for the necessary JavaScript to be loaded off your server.

Comment: Actually, you don't (at least not with 3.5+) -- if you are loading, it will automatically setup Loader. Again, you don't have any combo loading, though.