# YUI library on HTTPS

Tags: yui, mixed-content

My webapp uses YUI library exactly [as recommended in the doc](https://github.com/yui/yui3/wiki/Quick-Start):

```
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.18.1/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
```

**PROBLEM:** Modern browsers do not load it anymore, citing mixed HTTPS/HTTP concerns.

Replacing `http` with `https` in the URL above [does not work](https://yui.yahooapis.com/3.18.1/build/yui/yui-min.js) (they have a certificate problem).

Copying `yui-min.js` to my HTTPS domain does not work either, because the JavaScript seems to **contain its own URL** within its minified source code, for instance here:

```
[...] var p,b,q="3.4.1",h=".",n="http://yui.yahooapis.com/",t= [...]
```

I tried modifying the variable above directly in the minified code, but that broke things as now YUI for some reason tries to load `https://myserver/combo`, which obviously does not exist.

**QUESTION:** What is the right way to switch the YUI library to HTTPS?

http://blog.andrewbruce.net/why-is-serving-yui3-over-https-so-hard describes this problem as "*one of the most frustrating development problems I’ve come across in my career*", and describe how 3 techniques failed, and how he resorted to perform network sniffing and identify traffic for each browser he wanted to support. I would like to avoid this as I can not test on all browsers.

A recent glimmer of hope is the appearance of https://yui-s.yahooapis.com/combo?2.6.0/build/animation/animation-min.js which might lead to a usable HTTPS/YUI without having to go through much trouble.

*[Similar old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267371/what-is-the-right-way-to-use-yui3-with-https), but sole answer is based on [YUI Configurator, which has been deprecated](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/configurator/) and is now [unavailable](https://yuilibrary.com/yui/configurator/).*

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the "right" way to use YUI3 with HTTPS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267371/what-is-the-right-way-to-use-yui3-with-https)

Comment: @franciscod: No, the answer there is out-of-date, as [the YUI Configurator has been deprecated](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/configurator/)

Comment: [New answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42864665/4628327) at that question; changing the base URL from `http://yui.yahooapis.com/` to `https://yui-s.yahooapis.com/` seems to work. (_Whew!_)

Comment: I use the Version 3.17.2. I localized the yui-min.js to my server and replaced  http://yui.yahooapis.com/ with  https://yui-s.yahooapis.com in it. This just worked!